# Error al instalar Tomcat en Raspbian

Tags: servidor, tomcat, debian, raspbian

Estoy intentando instalar Tomcat en una maquinar virtual Raspbian en VirtualBox, he descargado varias vdi de la página de Osboxes, la de 2017, 2018 y las dos de 2019, siendo todas de 32 bits.

Estoy siguiendo la guia de el siguiente enlace: https://elbinario.net/2018/02/04/tutorial-instalacion-tomcat8-de-raspbian-stretch-en-una-raspberry-pi-3-con-java-de-oracle/

En ves de descargar la versión 8u161 estoy descargando la 8u261 me parece que es, la última que hay, pero a la hora de ejecutar el comando `make-jpkg jdk-8u261-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz` me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso es la versión 8u241 de 64 bits, pero he probado con un montón de versiones, las primeras veces con versiones de 32 bits como la del sistema operativo, probé con una de 64 por probar, pero el error es el mismo en todos los casos, que la arquitectura de i386 no es compatible, pero repito, he probado con varias versiones, tanto de 32 como de 64 bits y siempre me sale el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Cuál arquitectura tiene el host?

Comment: Como puedo mirarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Los hipervisores tipo 2 como VirtualBox no emulan hardware.

Un hipervisor 2 manda las instrucciones de la máquina virtual al sistema operativo del host, por lo que deben ser de la misma arquitectura. El conjunto de instrucciones de ARM (procesdor de Raspberry Pi) es distinto al de los procesadores Intel x86.

Considerando que Raspberry Pi Desktop es la versión para PC y Mac (arquitectura x86) de Debian con el mismo escritorio usado en Raspbian, en VirtualBox no podrás ejecutar código compilado para ARM.

Dicho lo anterior, deberías instalar el JDK para i386 ó x86_64 dependiendo del procesador donde esta instalado VirtualBox.